# Remove metadata tags using writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock: ios

Tags: iphone, ios, metadata, exif

I want to edit some metadata tags in iOS, and need to use [ALAssetsLibrary/writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum%3ametadata%3acompletionBlock%3a) since is the only method that doesn't re-encode pixel data.

In the specs of the metod it says:

> If there is a conflict between the metadata in the image data and the
>   metadata dictionary, the image data metadata values will be
>   overwritten.

My question is, can it also be used to remove meta tags? I ran some tests and set some `exif` values to `NSNull` as well as empty strings, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I was using `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:` and all of my metadata was getting stripped off, except that the orientation was getting saved to whatever argument I was passing. I saved using `ALAssetsLibrarywriteImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:` and passed my metadata, it saved it with the image.

I didn't try with this function without passing metadata.

Comment: Thanks, but I need some of the metadata tags to remain intact, and only part of them to be removed. I guess this could be done by exporting and afterwards editing the metadata, but at the moment I also need support for iOS 4.2+.